# Which Keystore was Used to Build a Release APK in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I created a new Flutter project and I built a release APK `flutter build apk` without creating a release Android keystore.

Which keystore did the Flutter use to build a release APK by default?

Comment: This might be helpfull. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8226

Comment: Refer to: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Comment: If you didn't specify a keystore in the properties file, my guess is that it is using a debug key to sign the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out the answer from Android app Gradle.

Flutter signs a release build using **debug keys** by default.

This line of comments found in ***android/app/build.gradle*** are very self explanatory.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```